# Use LINQ to transform single object into IEnumerable via Properties/reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, transform

I have a simple object like such:

```
public class Foo {
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
    ....
    public int Eleven { get; set; }
}
```

Given an IEnumerable, what I want is a LINQ method to transform as such:

```
myFooEnumerable.Select(n => transformMagicGoesHere);
```

Where my return object looks like this:

```
public class Bar {
    public string DurationDescription {get;set;} //Value would be "One" or "Two" or ...
    public int Value {get;set;} //Holds value in the property One or Two or ...
}
```

So for every item N in myFooEnumerable in the example above I'd get 11(N) items in my resultant select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var bars = myFooEnumerable.SelectMany(
    x => x.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => new Bar {
        DurationDescription = p.Name,
        Value = (int)p.GetValue(x)
    }));
```

Not a great thing to be doing in the first place, IMO, but it will at least work.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree its not ideal but this is a transformation for a report, it is not going in performance-sensitive code or used as a general business rule.